# Return false not working in my jquery ajax post, it sends to my php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm sorry everyone.. :( my bad I actually didn't include the jquery library...
Sorry for that :3 i'm just very exhausted right now.

can someone tell me what's wrong and/or lack of my codes? returning false is not working.... is there any conflict in the codes below?...

`html`

```
<form class="login-form" method="POST" action="loginauthenticate.php">
    <fieldset>

        <h3>WELCOME!</h3>
        <div id="get_content"></div>
        <p>
            <input class="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" required/>
            <br>
            <input class="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
            <br>
        </p>
        <input id="register" class="login-button" type="submit" value="Log In" />

    </fieldset>
</form>
<footer>
    <P>&copy; 2016 ACT Students,Thesis</P>
</footer>
```

`js`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form').submit(function() {
            $.ajax({
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                type: $(this).attr('method'),
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#get_content').html(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you can try `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: I replaced return false to event.preventDefault() but, it's not working in me..

Comment: What do you mean by "It is not working?"

Comment: It's working as expected for me here https://jsfiddle.net/jzk74qho/.

Comment: Are you using a separate js file for javascript ?

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/jzk74qho/3/

Comment: I'm sorry everyone.. :( my bad I actually didn't include the jquery library... Sorry for that :3 i'm just very exhausted right now.

Answer (score 0):

This works for preventing default and Ajax also fires. Try it again.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form').submit(function() {
            $.ajax({
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                type: $(this).attr('method'),
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#get_content').html(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I just tried it. It works for me here with his same code. Jayrex, are you including the JQuery library. Thats a bad question but thats the only possibility this code will not work.

Comment: I'm sorry everyone.. :( my bad I actually didn't include the jquery library... Sorry for that :3 i'm just very exhausted right now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `event.preventDefault()` and add `event` variable in `submit(function(event)`. The event parameter comes from the event binding function. This is the standart method that stops the default action of an element from happening. In oter words if this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

`return false;` does 3 separate things when you call it :

1.event.preventDefault(); – It stops the browsers default behaviour.

2.event.stopPropagation(); – It prevents the event from propagating (or “bubbling up”) the DOM.

3.Stops callback execution and returns immediately when called.

`preventDefault();` does one thing: It stops the browsers default behaviour.

So when to use them? Simply it depends on what you want to accomplish. Use preventDefault(); if you want to “just” prevent the default browser behaviour. Use return false; when you want to prevent the default browser behaviour and prevent the event from propagating the DOM. In most situations where you would use return false; what you really want is preventDefault().

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form').submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                type: $(this).attr('method'),
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#get_content').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

try to put return false before ajax work

```
 $('form').submit(function() {
        return false;
        $.ajax({
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            success: function(data) {
                $('#get_content').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: If you do that Ajax call will not fire :(

Comment: I'm sorry everyone.. :( my bad I actually didn't include the jquery library... Sorry for that :3 i'm just very exhausted right now.